# "\a" getting replaced with "BEL" in windows

Tags: windows, perl

I have a Perl script which executes a weblogic admin script this works fine in weblogic.But in windows its getting replaced

```
C:\kkk\aero\type\kmd\TM1.py
C:\kkkBELero\type\kmd\TM2.py
```

The bel character is getting replaced.

Any help?

Comment: Isn't `\t` getting replaced by the TAB character? And isn't `\k` also getting replaced by plain old `k`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The escape `"\a"` *is* the bell. If you want to have the literal sequence `\a`, you need to escape the backslash: `"\\a"` or use single quotes: `'\a'` or use forwards slashes for paths: `"C:/a/b/c"`.